# NextJs Mongodb NodeJs | best way to filter products by category

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, mongodb-query

I'm new to the **MERN Stack** and I'm building my first project but I'm stuck on finding a way to **filter products by category**
I was thinking of adding a **"Category"** field for each item in **MongoDB** but I had no idea how to show only this specific category
If you could give me a **general idea**, maybe an **example** or even a **resource** to learn from... because on YouTube I've seen A LOT of videos where they were filtering Static Products but in my case, I have a **database**, and I couldn't find anything that helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a category field and then just make a query for documents with some particular category.

```
const cursor = db.collection('inventory').find({ category: 'red' });
```

Here you are querying your collection "inventory" for the documents which have value "red" in their category field.

Here is MongoDB documentation about queries. Or your might want to use an ORM system, like [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) - it makes things little less complex.